# Is there a way I could express gcd as a linear combination of two numbers in more than 1 way?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

So given two numbers 30 and 22, I can compute the gcd as $3(30) - 4(22) = 2$ using the extended euclid's algorithm. However, is there a way I could express this with non-negative integers? That is a solution with no negative integer coefficients to the fixed numbers 30 and 22, and with the additional constraint that for some $a(30) - b(22)$, $0 \leq b < 30$

Comment: Are you asking if there are two natural numbers $a,b$ with $30a+22b=2$?

Comment: The answer to the ***title*** question is yes, there are infinitely many ways to express $2$ in the form $30a+22b$ with ***integers*** $a$ and $b,$ one positive and the other negative.

Comment: How do you prove it in such a way? I'm finding difficulty as I cannot find the gcd expressions without using a negative number.

Comment: "*I cannot find the gcd expressions without using a negative number*"  Of course.  Let $0<x\leq y$.  In the event that $x\mid y$ then $\gcd(x,y)=x=1\cdot x+0\cdot y$.  Otherwise, supposing that $x\nmid y$ one has $\gcd(x,y)$ is a divisor of $x$ different than $x$ itself which is therefore strictly *smaller* than $x$.  Letting $a,b$ be non-negative numbers, so long as either $a$ or $b$ is positive we have $ax+by\geq x>\gcd(x,y)$ and if $a=b=0$ we have $ax+by=0<\gcd(x,y)$.  As a result, clearly, at least one of $a$ or $b$ *must* be negative.

Comment: Now... if you were to allow $x$ or $y$ to be negative, then this doesn't necessarily work.  For example, $\gcd(-2,3)=1=1\cdot(-2)+1\cdot(3)$ got to avoid using any negative *coefficients*.  As for whether or not there exist multiple representations, let $ax+by=\gcd(x,y)$.  Then you also have $(a+ky)x+(b-kx)y=\gcd(x,y)$ for any $k$ since when you expand the $kxy$'s cancel, so there are in fact infinitely many such representations.

Comment: In such a case how can you find the additional kx and ky such that the answer remains?

Comment: Example: $\gcd(3,4)=1=-1\cdot 3+ 1\cdot 4$.  Using different letters just to avoid confusion, we can see that the following $(c,d)$ pairs satisfy $c\cdot 3 + d\cdot 4 = 1$.  The pairs $\dots,(-5,4),(-1,1),(3,-2),(7,-5),(11,-8),(15,-11),\dots,(-1+4k,1-3k),\dots$, for example $11\cdot 3 -8\cdot 4=33-32=1$.  "*How can you find the additional $kx$ and $ky$ such that the answer remains*" Keep adding $y$ to the first coefficient and subtract $x$ the same number of times from the second coefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$11 \cdot 30 - 15 \cdot 22 = 0\,$, so if $30a-22b=c$ then $30(a+11k)-22(b+15k)=c$ too. For example, with $a=3, b=4, c=2$ the next solution is $a+11=14, b+15=19\,$ i.e. $\,30 \cdot 14 - 22 \cdot 19 = 2\,$.

Comment: That's a very great insight. However, how do you get the values 11 and 15? especially when there are significantly larger numbers.

Comment: @oldselflearner1959 That's simply $\,\frac{n}{\gcd{(m,n)}} \cdot m - \frac{m}{\gcd{(m,n)}} \cdot n = 0\,$ for $m=30,n=22$.

Answer (score 1):

Surely you cannot have $2=30a+22b$ for non-negative $a,b$: either $a=b=0$ and RHS is then 0, or at least one of $a,b$ is nonzero, in which case the RHS is $\ge 22$ (if $b\gt 0$) or even $\ge 30$ (if $a\gt 0$).

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are is.For example gcd(3,2)=(-1)(3)+(2)(2)=(3)(3)-(4)(2).